# is number theory == natural analysis?

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, soft-question

I'm currently studying real analysis (beginner). What I think about this study is that it is about **studying all properties of real numbers** by the use of some basic axioms on it and also using other concepts/branches like field theory, order theory.

I feel like I should have studied something like "natural analysis" (analysis of natural numbers) first because I feel that naturally it should be the first one to study.

I have heard that number theory is a branch that studies integers (which includes natural numbers).

Is number theory == integer analysis and/or number theory == natural analysis?

Comment: We call it number theory... not those other names... but sure.  There really isn't that much overlap though.

Comment: If you want an introductory analysis text that begins with more fundamental notions (even more fundamental than the natural numbers), see [**Fundamentals of Abstract Analysis**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0867202092) by [Andrew Mattei Gleason](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrew_M._Gleason) (1966/1991; [review](https://maa.org/press/maa-reviews/fundamentals-of-abstract-analysis)).

Comment: There are many "other-branch" related concepts in real analysis which makes it uncomfortable to proceed with learning real analysis without first learning those "other" stuffs. This is a recursive path and time consuming. Should I trust my book's author and just learn what they have put iin the book? I started with real analysis and jumped to order theory and then to sets-relations and finally questioning myself what I have learnt all these years :(

Comment: Real analysis and number theory are not analogous topics in any useful sense, because the structures they study are so different. The Wikipedia pages on these topics might give you a good overview of what they are.

Comment: I suggest pursuing the topics you find the most interesting and making sure you understand the logical arguments there. You only need to learn an adjacent topic if theorems from it are needed. I don't think much number theory is used in real analysis.

Answer (score 1):

In mathematics, analysis as a larger field occupies itself with limits, continuity, and calculus.  Real analysis rigorously investigates the theoretical underpinnings of calculus over the real numbers.  As you have likely not done much investigation of calculus over the complex numbers, yet, that is the only form of calculus that you know.

Limits, continuity and calculus do not exist on the integers or the natural numbers.  So, it wouldn't be correct to discuss the mathematical structures over discrete sets "analysis."  Abstract algebra considers operations and structures over discrete sets, some of which are numbers and some of which are not.  Number theory, is indeed a deep dive into the behavior of natural numbers.  But, it has almost nothing to do with "analysis."

Comment: So, can I conclude that `real analysis is the study of properties of real numbers using all possible ways` and `Number theory is the same kind of study on Integers`? The apporoach and motive of those studies may be different to each other, but basically they both study properties of their respective domains. And if there's any other branches of mathematics which involve Integers or Reals, those branches can be called a sub-branch under these two, correspondingly.

Answer (score 0):

I would not say that, real analysis is like a toolbox that mathematicians use all the time. Number theory is a very broad topic, it is divided in subtopics and one of them is analytic number theory. It is heavily based on complex analysis which fits in more with your vision of things, that means that real analysis is analysis with real numbers and complex analysis with complex numbers. If you try to study analytic number theory, you'd understand the basic questions and problems that mathematicians ask themselves but you'll quickly have to deal with complex analysis. This is why I wouldn't recommend learning number theory before real/complex analysis. You can still learn about basic (analytic) number theory though because it's an interesting topic.

Answer (score 0):

*In a sense*, yes:

Formal first-order theories of arithmetic $-$ such as [Robinson arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson_arithmetic) or [Peano arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#Peano_arithmetic_as_first-order_theory) $-$ provide a setting/framework inside which 'number theory' as informally/commonly understood can be developed (at least to the extent that such 'number theory' deals with certain kinds of constructions made upon $\mathbb{N}, \mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$)

Modifying these theories (seemlingly) a bit (but in fact quite a lot) so that they become able to speak of 'sets of' (their first-order) objects $-$ as in 'full' second-order Peano arithmetic, or the 'restricted' [second-order arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-order_arithmetic) $-$, it turns out one can do real analysis (and more) inside them; as on Wikipedia:

> [...] second-order arithmetic allows quantification over sets of natural numbers as well as numbers themselves. Because real numbers can be represented as (infinite) sets of natural numbers in well-known ways, and because second-order arithmetic allows quantification over such sets, it is possible to formalize the real numbers in second-order arithmetic. For this reason, second-order arithmetic is sometimes called "analysis".

Note that it's also possible $-$ using stuff we know 'from the outside', ie, stronger set theories $-$ to speak of, say, continuous functions, since the real line is separable, and hence it suffices to specify only a countable list of pairs to uniquely determine 'the whole' function

[Feferman](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0049237X08711261) has:

> For example, the bulk of mathematical analysis may be developed within *the finite type structure over the natural numbers* $\mathbb{N}$ and indeed within type level three. (The type level of $\mathbb{N}$ is $0$, of $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ and of the real numbers is $1$, of the real functions is $2$, and of operators on such is $3$.)

Notice all this is somewhat different from the usual naïve approach of defining the reals as the unique order-complete field, but when using the latter people are, more often than not, not explicit about how they deal with real functions, etc., instead relying on some unspecified set or type theory

Long story short: yes, theories (presumably) about natural numbers and functions on them and other stuff are *very much analogous* to theories about real numbers and functions on them and stuff

Answer (score 0):

> it is about studying all properties of real numbers by the use of some basic axioms on it and also using other concepts/branches like field theory, order theory.

That is maybe the first week or so of "real analysis".

Beyond that you may study "functions on real numbers" ,  "families of subsets of real numbers" , "spaces of real-valued functions" , and so on.  All of these are items useful in the rest of analysis.